# knockout foreach update inside ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

The following is inside my ViewModel where I defined var self = this; I've got another foreach binding working in my code, but that one isn't in an ajax request. The initial UI load works. I know that self.wikiData is being updated by testing with console.log(self.wikiData());, but it's not updating in the UI. I've got something similar working outside the ajax request.

```js
self.wikiData = ko.observableArray([{title: ko.observable("testing"), url: ko.observable("code")}, {title: ko.observable("this"), url: ko.observable("works")}]);

$.ajax({
  url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + marker.title + "&callback=wikiCallBack",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(response) {
    // TODO figure out why ko array isnt updating
    // Clear wikiData array's contents
    self.wikiData = ko.observableArray([]);
    // articleList is just an array is strings
    var articleList = response[1];
    if (articleList.length < 1) {
      self.wikiData.push({
        title: ko.observable("No articles found"),
        url: ko.observable("#")
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
      articleStr = articleList[i];
      self.wikiData.push({
        title: ko.observable(articleStr),
        url: ko.observable("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + articleStr)
      });
    }
    // Push wiki attribution regardless of whether articles were found
    self.wikiData.push({
      title: ko.observable("Courtesy of Wikipedia API"),
      url: ko.observable("https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page")
    });
    //clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
    if (self.isWikiMenuVisible() === false) {
      self.clickHamburgerWiki();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: wikiData">
  <li class="wiki-list-item">
    <a data-bind="text: title, attr:{href: url}"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up removing the observables since I only need to keep track of the objects in the observableArray, and not manipulate the interior data of the objects themselves. Here's everything else:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + marker.title + "&callback=wikiCallBack",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(response) {
    // TODO figure out why ko array isnt updating
    // articleList is just an array is strings
    var articleList = response[1];
    var tempArray = [];
    if (articleList.length < 1) {
      tempArray.push({
        title: "No articles found",
        url: "#"
      });
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
        articleStr = articleList[i];
        tempArray.push({
          title: articleStr,
          url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + articleStr
        });
      }
    }
    tempArray.push({
      title: "Courtesy of Wikipedia API",
      url: "https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page"
    });
    // Clear wikiData array's contents by redefining with new content
    self.wikiData.removeAll();
    tempArray.forEach(function(item) {
      self.wikiData.push(item);
    });
    // Push wiki attribution regardless of whether articles were found
    //clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
    if (self.isWikiMenuVisible() === false) {
      self.clickHamburgerWiki();
    }
  }
});
```

HTML stayed the same.

Turns out, the way to get KO to recognize updates was to use the removeAll() function to empty the observableArray and then push new objects into it, rather than reassign the observableArray to an empty array. This makes sense since the reassignment removed the previously set bindings, while removeAll() leaves them.